# How to search for a pattern within a string?

Tags: c#

I have a string which contains the following output

```
login;windows
db;sql
audit;failure
```

how do I check if this string contains the word "audit;failure"?

I have use the following code  but was not successful:

```
 currLine = sr.ReadToEnd();
 string[] splited = Regex.Split(currLine, "~~~~~~~~~~~~~~");
 case1 = splited[0];
 string case1 = "";
 string pattern1 = "audit;failure";
 if (Regex.IsMatch(case1, pattern1)){
 console.writeline("success"!);
}
```

I must search through the variable `case1` and not the string currLine
thaks in advance! :D

Comment: have you tried [string.Contains](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dy85x1sa.aspx)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Also make sure that you remove the line `string case1 = "";`

```
if(case1.Contains("audit;failure"))
   console.writeline("success"!);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need to adjust case1 string ........

```
 string case1 = "";
 currLine = sr.ReadToEnd();
 string[] splited = Regex.Split(currLine, "~~~~~~~~~~~~~~");
 case1 = splited[0];
 string pattern1 = "audit;failure";
 if (Regex.IsMatch(case1, pattern1)){
 console.writeline("success"!);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply use [`String.Contains()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dy85x1sa.aspx#Y0), use a code like follows

```
if(sr.Contains("audit;failure")
{

}
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it would be to split this first into the lines.

```
string[] lines = sr.split (new string[]{ Environment.LineBreak});
foreach(string line in lines){
    string[] parts = line.split(new char[] {';'});
    if(parts[0] == "audit")
        return parts[1];
}
return "not set";
```

This will return whatever stands behind "audit" and is easily adaptable to return whatever you need. The final return will be triggered if no audit-line was present.